# redirection if some variable is missing creates an error saying the variable is missing

Tags: php, redirect

if there is no `id` in url I want to get the `id` from database and then redirect to the same page using the `id`

```
if(!isset($_GET['id'])){
    $st = $db->query("select id from video where ind = 0 limit 1");
    $st->execute();
    $id = $st->fetchColumn();
    header('location: index.php?id='.$id);
}

$urid = $_GET['id']; // line 15
```

everything works, page is redirected and `id` is there but the system creates an error.log file saying:

```
Undefined array key "id" ... on line 15
```

so why the system creates this error
redirection should happens before `line 15`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should have `exit;` next to the redirect

```
<?php
    header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect browser */
    
    /* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
    exit;
    ?>
```

Comment: it works thanks, but what is the logic? how the code can be executed before it is reached.  php is not async, isn't it?

Comment: There are two special-case header calls... one is `location` and another is `HTTP/`. For location, we must use exit, otherwise the code below will get executed

Comment: Normally, questions that have been answered repeatedly before shouldn't be answered.  The duplicate should provide enough resources to explain the solution.  If you feel as though you can add to that question, then do so on the linked question and not here.